# Как запустить анимацию перехода между активити с общим элементом после создания второй активити

Tags: java, android, анимация, activity, transition

Есть задача, при переходе с одной актвити на другую, "перемещается" общий элемент (ImageView), во второй активити есть RecyclerView куда эта картинка и попадает. Вопрос, как запустить анимацию перехода с общим элементом, после того как вторая активтити будет создана? Обратная анимация работает. У меня есть подозрение, из-за того, что во второй активити, где RecyclerView, анимация не отрабатывает так как в этот момент еще не установлен адаптер recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter); Как тогда запустить анимацию?

Answer (score 1):

В общем сам отвечу на свой вопрос, во второй активити, где RecyclerView куда "прилетает" картинка, нужно сначало остановить показ анимации. Перед setContentView() установить postponeEnterTransition()

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    postponeEnterTransition();
}

setContentView(R.layout.activity_task);
```

И в адаптере RecyclerView вызвать через интерфейс метод setStartPostTransition().

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TaskRecyclerViewHolder viewholder, int position) {

            viewholder.imageView.setTag(position);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                viewholder.imageView.setTransitionName("anim");

                iView.setStartPostTransition(viewholder.imageView);
            }        

    }
```